# How to pass information from one void to another?

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I have a simple problem that I cannot find the solution anywhere for.

All I would need is to pass information from one `void` to another.

I have tried to find a solution but many solutions go on for passing information from class to class and script to script, and that's not exactly what I need and none have worked.

The Code right now is something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){   
  GetVoid.DoCheck();
}

public void GenerateInformation(){
  DateTime StoredDateTime;
  //Code that does something
  StoredDateTime = //Date generated from the rest of the code not included
}

public void DoCheck(){
  DateTime CheckedDateTime;
  GenerateInformation();
  CheckedDateTime = StoredDateTime;
  //Rest of the code for that void
}
```

My end goal is for the date so simply be stored in the other `DateTime` but I get the error

> The name 'StoredDateTime' does not exist in the current context.

As far as I know this is because it does not know what `StoredDateTime` is, and to fix this I would need to pass on the information from one void to the other.

But how would I do that?

Comment: Do you know the english word "void"? In the context of C#, it means the **abscence** of a return type (or value). A method with return type `void` does not and cannot return anything. That is what the keyword `void` means ("_there is a void where otherwise there would be a return value_", so to speak). If you want a method to return an object/value of some type, you need to declare the return type of that method accordingly (change the return type from `void` to whatever you need...) Please spend some time with C# tutorials teaching about writing methods and how to return values  from methods.

Comment: Why don't you make `GenerateInformation()` return value of `StoredDateTime `?

Comment: Is there any reason your functions **need** to be void? You could easily fix your problem if GenerateInformation was a function returning the StoredDateTime.

Comment: You're using the phrase "pass information from" when I think you mean "return information from"; you want `GenerateInformation()` to make its results available to `DoCheck()`.  If that's the case, why is `GenerateInformation()` a `void` method?  Where did that (lack of) return type requirement come from?

Comment: If you want to "pass" information, you would use parameters.  If you want to "return" information, you would use a function.

Comment: I was literally seconds away from posting an answer that I think dealt with the OP's issue - I think there's a simple misunderstanding of how to persist *within a class* the information created within a void function such that another void method in the same class can access it - and these are presumably both methods in a class. The issue is to move the StoredDateTime declaration to a class variable. I'm inferring the OP simply omitted some of the class decoration code that might have made the problem a bit more self-evident. Hope this helps, sorry I didn't beat the close police.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

void mean:

- not valid or legally binding.
- completely empty.

So, you cannot expect from void method to pass you result. You need to change your method signature and implement return.

```
public static DateTime GetDate()
{
    var dateVal = DateTime.Now;
    return dateVal;
}
```

then

```
public static void Main(string[] args){   
    var dateRetult = GetDate();
    Console.WriteLine(dateResult);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed "void GenerateInformation" to "DateTime GenerateInformation", and in 'GenerateInformation' added "return StoredDateTime;".

Then in the void I added "var StoredDateTime = GenerateInformation();" and it worked.